# How to convert a nested JSON into ordered columns without using pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list, api

I have spent days trying to solve this problem. This was the most effective way I could find how to iterate this object: I get the result, but when I use pandas the DataFrame structure is not correct. So I was exploring the idea of ​​creating the columns without pandas, but I don't get the expected result.

Any idea how I could improve this code?

Sample data:

```
{
  "financeCodeId": "fc-5599",
  "financeData": [
    {
      "date": "2022-01-30",
      "calcTotalReturn": 0.022425456852
    },
    {
      "date": "2022-01-30",
      "calcTotalReturn": 0.022425456852
    },
    {
      "date": "2022-01-30",
      "calcTotalReturn": 0.022425456852
    },
    {
      "date": "2022-01-30",
      "calcTotalReturn": 0.022425456852
    },
    {
      "date": "2022-01-30",
      "calcTotalReturn": 0.022425456852
    }, 
    {
      "date": "2022-02-28",
       "calcTotalReturn": -0.0424735070051586,
       "financeDataAttributes": [
       {
         "attributeId": "a-256",
         "value": "12.032791372796499"
       },
       {
       "attributeId": "a-257",
       "value": "9.975964795996589"
       },
       {
       "attributeId": "a-258",
       "value": "4.719852927810759"
       },
       {
       "attributeId": "a-259",
       "value": "4.18144793134823"
       },     
    ]
}
```

Code:

```
            items = []
            for i in response_finance['results']:
                items.append(i.get('financeCodeId'))
                for j in i['financeData']:
                    if 'financeDataAttributes' not in j:
                        items.append({j.get('date'), j.get('calcTotalReturn')})
                    else:
                        for k in j['financeDataAttributes']:
                            items.append({k.get('attributeId'), k.get('value')})
    df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(items)

    flat = pd.json_normalize(json.loads(df.to_json(orient="records")))
```

Output

[image: out put]

Expected:

[image: Expected]

Comment: You preferred not using `pandas` because it's producing the wrong format? Or there is another consideration?

Comment: Not using pandas would be another consideration, I'm open to a solution with pandas.

Comment: It's just that I have several days dealing with pandas that I thought maybe another approach could work better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you already go through your json manually, you don't need `json_normalize`. You can create your own flattened record (I fixed the formatting of your json, check if it matches your real data):

```
response_finance = [{
  "financeCodeId": "fc-5599",
  "financeData": [
    {
      "date": "2022-01-30",
      "calcTotalReturn": 0.022425456852
    },
    {
      "date": "2022-01-30",
      "calcTotalReturn": 0.022425456852
    },
    {
      "date": "2022-01-30",
      "calcTotalReturn": 0.022425456852
    },
    {
      "date": "2022-01-30",
      "calcTotalReturn": 0.022425456852
    },
    {
      "date": "2022-01-30",
      "calcTotalReturn": 0.022425456852
    }, 
    {
      "date": "2022-02-28",
       "calcTotalReturn": -0.0424735070051586,
       "financeDataAttributes": [
       {
         "attributeId": "a-256",
         "value": "12.032791372796499"
       },
       {
       "attributeId": "a-257",
       "value": "9.975964795996589"
       },
       {
       "attributeId": "a-258",
       "value": "4.719852927810759"
       },
       {
       "attributeId": "a-259",
       "value": "4.18144793134823"
       },     
      ]
    }
  ]
}
]
```

```
items = []
for i in response_finance:
    for j in i['financeData']:
        if 'financeDataAttributes' not in j:
            item = {}
            item['financeCodeId'] = i.get('financeCodeId')
            item.update({'date': j.get('date'), 'calcTotalReturn': j.get('calcTotalReturn')})
            items.append(item)
        else:
            for k in j['financeDataAttributes']:
                item = {}
                item['financeCodeId'] = i.get('financeCodeId')
                item.update({'date': j.get('date'), 'calcTotalReturn': j.get('calcTotalReturn')})
                item.update({'attributeId': k.get('attributeId'), 'value': k.get('value')})
                items.append(item)

df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(items)

print(df)
```

Output:

```
  financeCodeId        date  calcTotalReturn attributeId               value
0       fc-5599  2022-01-30         0.022425         NaN                 NaN
1       fc-5599  2022-01-30         0.022425         NaN                 NaN
2       fc-5599  2022-01-30         0.022425         NaN                 NaN
3       fc-5599  2022-01-30         0.022425         NaN                 NaN
4       fc-5599  2022-01-30         0.022425         NaN                 NaN
5       fc-5599  2022-02-28        -0.042474       a-256  12.032791372796499
6       fc-5599  2022-02-28        -0.042474       a-257   9.975964795996589
7       fc-5599  2022-02-28        -0.042474       a-258   4.719852927810759
8       fc-5599  2022-02-28        -0.042474       a-259    4.18144793134823
```

Comment: Yes, you have the correct structure, with these changes  now I have the expected result, thank you very much for helping me with this problem.